# Why Doesn't Array Concatenation Work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I create two arrays in JavaScript and try to concatenate them using the `concat` keyword, the resulting array is always empty (well, the things from the array that should be inserted are not inserted). I couldn't imagine this is actually how JS is supposed to work because then... what would be the point of the `concat` keyword if it does nothing?

So then I must be doing something wrong, but I'm following the docs exactly.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/webwhizjim/7z4v33of/

```
// Example with objects- doesn't work...
var greetings = [{"affirmative":"yeah"}];
var exclamations = [{"omg":"Oh my golly-gee-wilickers!"},{"wowz":"wowzers!"}];

var obArray = [];

obArray.concat(greetings);
console.log("The jumble array is: " + obArray);

// Example with strings- still doesn't work...

var greetings2 = ["affirmative","yeah"];
var exclamations2 = ["omg"];

var obArray2 = ["huh?"];

[].concat.call(obArray2, greetings2);
console.log("The jumble array is: " + obArray2);
```

Just to be clear by "it doesn't work" I mean the console output is this:

[image]

PS. In my real project I'm using Angular 1.4; so, if there's a way to `concat` arrays with that, I'm open to it.

Comment: `concat` returns a new array, it doesn't mutate.

Comment: ^ `obArray2 = obArray2.concat(greetings2)`

Comment: also, the first argument of `Function.prototype.call` defines the context of the call (the value of `this`), not the first array to concatenate

Comment: @Sebas true, but it turns out it's correct in this case; it's just redundant with the first example.

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 2):

`.concat()` creates a new array and returns it.  It does not add elements onto an existing array.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> concat creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on
>   which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument, the
>   elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the
>   argument itself (if the argument is not an array).
>
> concat does not alter this or any of the arrays provided as arguments
>   but instead returns a shallow copy that contains copies of the same
>   elements combined from the original arrays. Elements of the original
>   arrays are copied into the new array as follows:

You can add elements onto an existing array with `.splice()` or with `.push()`.

```js
var greetings2 = ["affirmative","yeah"];
var obArray2 = ["huh?"];
obArray2.push.apply(obArray2, greetings2);

// display result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(obArray2));
```

---

Or, just use the newly returned array from `.concat()`:

```js
    var greetings2 = ["affirmative","yeah"];
    var obArray2 = ["huh?"];
    var newArray = obArray2.concat(greetings2);

    // display result in snippet
    document.write(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, `.concat` returns a new array, and does not mutate the original state of the arrays you are working with. If you want the value of two arrays being joined via `.concat` you must store it in a variable or simply do the concatenation it where you need it.

example:

```
var greetings = [{"affirmative":"yeah"}];
var exclamations = [{"omg":"Oh my golly-gee-wilickers!"},{"wowz":"wowzers!"}];

var obArray = greetings.concat(exclamations);

console.log(obArray); // returns [obj, obj, obj]
```

This would give you the same result:

```
console.log(greetings.concat(exclamations));
```

One last thing. Methods like `.concat` are chain-able.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var greetings = [{"affirmative":"yeah"}];
var exclamations = [{"omg":"Oh my golly-gee-wilickers!"}, {"wowz":"wowzers!"}];

var obArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], greetings, exclamations);
console.log("The jumble array is: " + obArray);
//Console Output: The jumble array is: [object Object]

var greetings2 = ["affirmative","yeah"];
var exclamations2 = ["omg"];

var obArray2 = [].concat(greetings2, exclamations2);
console.log("The jumble array is: " + obArray2);
//Console Output: The jumble array is: affirmative,yeah,omg
```